# how to push elements in array of objects from api to new array vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, vue.js, object

i want to push the first 6 elements from an array of objects to my freshly made array.
I get it out on the webbrowser but instead or "qwe" "qweqweqwe" i get NaN. Why?

Lets say the array of objects from the api looks like this:

```
0: {id: 340, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
1: {id: 341, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
2: {id: 342, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
3: {id: 343, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
4: {id: 344, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
5: {id: 345, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
6: {id: 346, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
7: {id: 347, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
8: {id: 348, name: "qwe", lastname: "qweqweqweq", …}
```

and my code looks like this:

```
.then(response => {
                console.log(typeof response.data, response.data);
                this.model = {
                    name: response.data.name,
                    lastname: response.data.lastname
                }
                this.userInfo.unshift(this.model.name + this.model.lastname); // Here's where i have problem
                if(this.userInfo.length > 6)
                    this.userInfo.pop();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Something went wrong', error);
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you, you want to push the first 6 elements from `response` to `userInfo`.

If that is what you want you can try like this:

```
.then(response => {
    response.data.some((e, index) => {
          this.userInfo.push(e.name + e.lastname)
          return index > 5
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you, but now im getting it as an object on the screen
like this: { "name": "qwe", "lastname": "qweqweqweqweq" }
i only want the value of name and lastname.

Comment: @gospecomid12 Oh, ok you need it like string, I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks man, i should have figured it out by my own but my brain is so tired,
going for a walk now :p

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because `response.data` doesn't contain the fields `name` and `lastname` as `undefined + undefined` will result in `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to move first six entries of the array objects, then you can use this method

```
let newArray = response.data.slice(0, 6); // the newArray will have the first six objects of the response data.
```